# Parameter specified as non-null is null with BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to display bottomSheetDialog when there's no internet available. the code that I used is

```
    private fun setupBottomSheetDialog() {
    bottomSheetDialog =
        object : BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme) {
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setOnKeyListener { _: DialogInterface?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent ->
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        // Back key is pressed
                        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss() // Optional
                        requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true) //exit the app when press back
                        requireActivity().finish()
                        return@setOnKeyListener true
                    }
                    true
                }
            }
        }
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_no_internet)
    bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false)
}
```

---

```
@SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
private fun showBottomSheetDialog() {
    bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme)
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_no_internet)
    if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(requireActivity())) {
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
    } else {
        setupBottomSheetDialog()
    }
    /* Try Again Button */
    val buttonNoInternet = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonAgain)
    buttonNoInternet?.setOnClickListener {
        if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(requireActivity())) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
        } else {
            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            bottomSheetDialog.show()
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
    override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(requireActivity())) {
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
    } else {
        bottomSheetDialog.show()
    }
}
```

---

the problem that I have is in **onResume()** mehoud. and the error message that I got is

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter savedInstanceState
> at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.view.fragment.HomeFragment$setupBottomSheetDialog$1.onCreate(Unknown Source:2)
> at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:616)
> at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:460)
> at com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.view.fragment.HomeFragment.onResume(HomeFragment.kt:143)

***and In top of error message***

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth/com.moataz.afternoonhadeeth.ui.view.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter savedInstanceState
> ```

---

**Note: is code is working fine with Java. But when I use it with kotlin it is give me the error. Any Idea how to solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have found the problem. I should add `savedInstanceState: Bundle?` in on create method in bottomdialog. I will leave the question here if anyone wants to know how to use BottomDialog correctly in his app.
Have a good day.